# OpenGL triangle rotates wrong

Tags: c, opengl, rotation, glut, glm-math

I want to rotate my triangle around his own axis, but It´s rotating around the camera.
I have to code from a tutorial, the only differenc is, that I´m using C instead of C++. So I have to use the "cglm"-lib instead of the "glm"-lib.
(I´m also using glut and glad)

globally defined:

```c
mat4  model;
mat4 projection;
mat4 view;
mat4 modelViewProj;
```

In the main:

```c
glm_mat4_identity(model); //Einheitsmatrix
glm_mat4_identity(view);
glm_scale(model, (vec3) {1.2f, 1.2f, 1.2f});

glm_perspective(glm_rad(45.0f), 4.0f/3.0f, 0.1f, 100.0f, projection);

glm_translate(view, (vec3) {0, 0, -5.0f});

glm_mat4_mul(model, projection, modelViewProj);
glm_mat4_mul(modelViewProj, view, modelViewProj);

modelMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shader1.shaderId, "u_modelViewProj");
```

In the loop:

```c
//In the void display()
glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMatrixLocation,1, GL_FALSE, &modelViewProj[0][0]); 

//In the void update() ->glutTimerFunc()
glm_rotate(model, 0.08f, (vec3){0, 1, 0});

glm_mat4_mul(model, projection, modelViewProj);
glm_mat4_mul(modelViewProj, view, modelViewProj);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The order of the matrix multiplications is wrong.

It has to be:

```
modelViewProj = projection * view * model;
```

In C:

```c
glm_mat4_mul(view, model, modelViewProj);
glm_mat4_mul(projection, modelViewProj, modelViewProj);
```

Note, [`void glm_mat4_mul(mat4 m1, mat4 m2, mat4 dest)`](https://cglm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/mat4.html#c.glm_mat4_mul) computes:

```
dest = m1 * m2;
```

[Matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) is not [Commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) (in compare to [Arithmetic Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic#Multiplication_(%C3%97_or_%C2%B7_or_*))). The order matters.

Comment: Thank you, It´s working, but why? I´ve learned in school, that i can change the order of the products in a multiplication and it´s still the same.

Comment: @SouperFishɗɦʅ No, the [Matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) is not [Commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) (in compare to [Arithmetic Multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic#Multiplication_(%C3%97_or_%C2%B7_or_*))). The order matters.

Comment: Ok, I think I have to wait a bit until i have matrices and vectors in school.